# ViewModel for layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

This is probably a basic question, but so far I can not figure out how to solve this probably.

I have a `_Layout.cshtml` which has some markup to describe which user is logged in. This information is stored in my database, so I need to retrieve this on all my views.

My application contains a lot of views and this information needs to be displayed on all pages.

How do I solve this, without having to get this information on all my controllers?

**Update, my solution was this, using @Jayesh Goyani guidance:**

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetDashboardView()
{
    var model = new DashboardModel();
    /* fill model from database */
    return model != null ? PartialView("_DashboardView", model) : null;
}
```

With an `_DashboardView` located in my `/Views/Dashboard/_DashboardView.cshtml`:

```
@model DashboardViewModel

<p>@Model.MyProperty</p>
```

And used like this in my `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("GetDashboardView", "Dashboard");}
```

Comment: You can render some action which will get all data you need from database in your layout view. `@Html.RenderAction("action" ...)` And return partial view by this action with user specific data.

Comment: @meep I had a similar problem before. My search back then led my to the solution to use `BaseController` and all other controllers extending this controller. By doing this you will have to use `ViweBag` but you will also have one place where to manage all this kind of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way is to call Html.RenderAction() inside the layout file, where you want the user-specific details. Then create a suitable Action method somewhere which reads the user's account details and returns them as a view (partial view) or as raw html (return Content("...")).

That way, you can also benefit the ability to cache the layout page and keep the user's account details region uncached (since it's obviously different for every user).

Setting a ViewBag is not a good idea, it's not strongly type and it breaks the correct schema of MVC. By using [Filtering in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28vs.98%29.aspx) you can add the user detail into viewbag on every request.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up with. :-)

Comment: Updated my question with solution for other users :-)